# Heroku cannot store files temporarily

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am writing a nodejs app which works with fonts. One action it performs is that it downloads a .ttf font from the web, converts it to a base64 string, deletes the .ttf and uses that string in other stuff. I need the .ttf file stored somewhere, so I convert it. This process takes like 1-2 seconds. I know heroku has an ephemeral file system but I need to store stuff for such a short time. Is there any way I can store my files? Using fs.writeFile currently returns this error:

> Error: EROFS: read-only file system, open '/app\test.txt']

Answer (score 0):

I had idea how about you make an action, That would get font, convert it and store it on a global variable before used by another task.

When you want to use it again, make sure you check that global variable already filled or not with that font buffer.

Reference

- [Singleton](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/singleton-class-java/)

Comment: The problem is, the module which I am using to convert to base64 ie [node-font2base64](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-font2base64) only accepts a path not a buffer.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know that you could store stuff in /tmp directory. It is working for the moment but according to the dyno/ephemeral system, it gets cleaned frequently so I don't know if it may cause other problems in the long run.